# can cross-validation solve the issue of confidence interval interpretation?

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation

I want to approach a true parameter value, and my chances of obtaining it, but I struggle to accept the subjectivity of bayesian credible intervals just as much as I can't see the value of a normal interpretation of confidence intervals.

does cross-validation aid me in the endeavor?
I have also read that the parameter is fixed and the confidence interval random, what does this mean? I know that the sample estimate approaches population values given CLT, but not much more.

Comment: Do you mean splitting the data into K folds, using K-1 to get a CI, checking that it covers the mean of the remaining fold, and then averaging in hopes of seeing 0.95? If so, I am not sure if that mimics the promise of a CI. But I am not sure what else you could have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> does cross-validation aid me in the endeavor?

No.

> I have also read that the parameter is fixed and the confidence interval random, what does this mean?

In the frequentist paradigm, the parameter (or estimand) is considered fixed.  This means that it does not vary.  Were we to get lots and lots of datasets, each with millions of observations, then the estimated value from each dataset would be approximately the same.

So the estimand does not change from sample to sample, but the confidence interval does.  Indeed, the confidence interval is a function of the data, which are random, so the confidence interval is random.

> but I struggle to accept the subjectivity of bayesian credible intervals

This is a non sequitur for me.  What I assume you're referring to is the priors.  That Bayes is somehow "subjective" is an old view in my opinion.  If I show you my priors, and I describe how I came about them, and they reflect the current state of knowledge about a problem, and you agree that while maybe they not be perfect they are reasonable approximations to what is known about the estimand, then in what sense are they subjective?  If I pulled the priors out of my -- ahem, "posterior" -- then that's poor practice but for reasons which are can not be boiled down to "subjectivity" alone.

I like [this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/gelman_hennig_full_discussion.pdf) paper on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I see partly where I went wrong, this isn't my main field of study. If you wouldn't mind, could you explain then the value of presenting confidence intervals (as recommended by APA) when it is considered random (a.k.a. 95% of confidence intervals constructed containing the true parameter value)?

Comment: @Eric the 95% in “95% confidence interval” means that upon repeated construction under ideal identical conditions, 95% of intervals will contain the estimand. The value is that, if the model assumptions are true, then the confidence interval very likely contains the true estimand.

Comment: Another way to put this: the confidence interval contains parameters which are consistent with the data. If a parameter value is outside the interval, then the data are not consistent with that parameter value (at the given confidence level). You’re free to search confidence interval interpretations on this site.